# Comparing elements

Tags: jquery

```
for (index=1; index<=15; index++) {
    if (undefined != sku[index]) {

        found = jQuery.inArray(sku[index], mr_sku); 
        if( found == -1){ //not in array
            alert( sku[index] + " NOT FOUND - delete index " + index );
        } else { // in array
                  alert("FOUND");
        }

  }
```

}

Two arrays - sku and mr_sku = trying to find the values from 1 to 15 where not undefined that the values are in both arrays. sku[1] and mr_sku I know are the SAME value - Just NEVER shows as bieng in the array - inarray ALWAYS comes back as -1

Comment: Do you have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates the failure?

Comment: arrays start from 0 so if with `sku[1]` you mean the first value, then you should really use `sku[0]` ..

Answer (score 0):

Tested with dummy data and it is working fine. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/mMZjh/) and here is the data I used:

```
var sku = ['a','b','c'];
var mr_sku = ['a','c','c'];

for (index=1; index<=2; index++) {
    if (undefined != sku[index]) {

        found = jQuery.inArray(sku[index], mr_sku); 
        if( found == -1){ //not in array
            alert( sku[index] + " NOT FOUND - delete index " + index );
        } else { // in array
                  alert("FOUND");
        }

  }
}​
```